# Drupal User Creation SMTPS message fails

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7, smtp, starttls

I'm using Drupal 7. When I add a user via Peoples > + Add User, I want the user to receive a notification e-mail.

If I tick the box: " Notify user of new account ", and then click "Create New Account", the page redirects to a blank page at "/admin/people/create". The user IS created, but no message is sent. There isn't even a log for an attempt to send an SMTP message in Drupal, or a failure etc. But the user exists.

If I DON'T tick the box, then the user is still properly created, but I don't get stuck at a blank page (the page is refreshed and I can see the green checkmark saying my changes have been applied)

How can I investigate this problem? I would like the e-mail to be sent (and I assume the blank page problem is related/the same issue) Like I said, I see no logs of e-mail trying to be sent, but it only crashes when I try to do so. Perhaps there's some other logs/debugging info I can enable?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. The Token module was broken, and my user registration message used tokens, so this is why it crashed on user registration but not SMTP test.

Re-installing a fresh copy of the Token module fixed it.